Special Regular Expression match in javascript
I need JavaScript special regex pattern to convert the input string to required string.
Input String:
google.com/q=abc?param1=\[foo,bar\]&optional=true&param2=\[bar,baz\]

Output String:
google.com/q=abc?param1=foo&optional=true&param2=bar

This is my code.
function transformUrl(inputUrl) {
  var pattern = /\[([^,\]]+),([^,\]]+)\]/g;
  var outputUrl = inputUrl.replace(pattern, function (match, group1) {
    return group1;
  });
  return outputUrl;
}

var inputUrl = "google.com/q=abc?aparam1=[foo,bar]&optional=true&param2=[bar,baz]";
var outputUrl = transformUrl(inputUrl);
console.log(outputUrl); // google.com/q=abc?aparam1=foo&optional=true¶m2=bar`

As you can see, main problems is solved but '&para' string has been changed to '¶' string.
How can I fix this issue?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Don't use a Regex for that. Use a URL parser.

The regex answers here seem overcomplex, you don't really need to match both groups independently and you also don't need to use the function callback. This should do it const output = input.replace(/\[([^,]+)[^\]]+\]/g, '$1')

@jmcgriz
please check this.,https://playcode.io/1886524

@BeautifulPine That issue where it's turning &para into a paragraph tag appears to be a glitch with that playcode site. If you use a browser console directly or codepen it works fine

You can simplify this by looking at each parameter in turn using the URL API instead of trying to do it all at once.
This assumes that you have a URL which includes a protocol (e.g. http: or https:). It should be trivial to prepend one of you don't though and remove it afterwards


// We need a complete URL including protocol
const url = new URL('https://google.com/q=abc?param1=\[foo,bar\]&optional=true&param2=\[bar,baz\]');

// iterate of each search parameter
for (let [key, value] of url.searchParams){

  // does the value look like an array
  const matches = value.match(/\[([^,]+)/);
  if (matches){
    // grab the second (last) value from the array
    // and update the url
    url.searchParams.set(key, matches[1]);
  }
}

console.log(url.href);
// outputs: https://google.com/q=abc?param1=foo&optional=true&param2=bar




If you want to use regex then, use anyone of them, which is better for your:


function transformUrl(inputUrl) {
var pattern = /\[([^,\]]+),([^,\]]+)\]/g;
return inputUrl.replace(pattern, (x) => x.split(',')[0].replace(/[\[\]]/gi, '').trim());
}

var inputUrl = "google.com/q=abc?aparam1=[foo,bar]&optional=true&param2=[bar,baz]";
var outputUrl = transformUrl(inputUrl);
console.log(outputUrl); // google.com/q=abc?aparam1=foo&optional=true&param2=bar



or


function transformUrl(inputUrl) {
var pattern = /\[([^,\]]+),([^,\]]+)\]/g;
var pattern2 = /(?<=\[)[\w+\d+]+(?=[\,\]])/gi; // match first element in [foo,bar]
return inputUrl.replace(pattern, (x) => x.match(pattern2).toString());
}

var inputUrl = "google.com/q=abc?aparam1=[foo,bar]&optional=true&param2=[bar,baz]";
var outputUrl = transformUrl(inputUrl);
console.log(outputUrl); // google.com/q=abc?aparam1=foo&optional=true&param2=bar




Doublecheck your output - if your comment is accurate it's still converting "param2" into a paragraph tag

URL parser is best way to resolve this issue and corresponding answer already here. I tried to resolve this issue using regex according to question description. That's why I mention in header: If you want to use regex @jmcgriz

Understood - just saying in your code snippets above, it has this // google.com/q=abc?aparam1=foo&optional=true¶m2=bar, which is broken output and either copy/pasted incorrectly or not a valid answer since it's broken

I don't understand what you are saying ? @jmcgriz
Here input is: google.com/q=abc?aparam1=[foo,bar]&optional=true&param2=[bar,baz] and if I add 'https://' with this input then,
Both input are working fine: https://i.sstatic.net/Xfy8lucg.png

That's great that it's working - I'm suggesting you update your answer then. Scroll up and look at the last line of both code blocks in your answer where it reads like this: console.log(outputUrl); // google.com/q=abc?aparam1=foo&optional=true¶m2=bar

Yes, right, that was copy pasted from question input. This was my wrong, I now corrected that.  Thank you @jmcgriz
